# MySql Workbench: row returns after delete

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySql workbench. When I delete rows in my dummy database, it's deleted. But afterwards, upon a fresh query the rows are back.

I've restarted my pc and workbench. Is there some queue that can be viewed and emptied in MySql workbench? Or how to persist the delete?

Comment: Have you `COMMIT`-ted your `DELETE`?

Comment: Aaaahh... Did not realize to commit the delete after using interface to delete. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL you can turn on the general log to log all queries being run.  From there you can check whether your delete statement actually ran.  It's likely that either

1. The delete statement isn't running at all, in which case you can debug your Node.js app.  Usagi suggests you might be missing a `COMMIT`
2. The delete statement is running, but with an incorrect `WHERE` for example, so the row you're expecting isn't actually getting deleted, even if your delete statement is.

You can do this by running:
`set global general_log = 'On';` (remember to turn this off when you're finished).

To see the directory where the log is you can run `show variables where variable_name = 'datadir';`

Comment: Thanks. The logging will help for future issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing it from interface not from SQL query then
There is apply and revert button
after you delete the rows click on apply to make the changes effective, otherwise the data will remain there even after you delete it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).